# ref.current is always undefined?

Tags: reactjs, react-forwardref

I need to use functional component ,so I can't use useRef directly. here is my code:

```js
import React,{forwardRef,useImperativeHandle,useRef,useEffect} from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {


  const ref_ = useRef();

useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(ref_)

})
  console.log(ref_)

  return (
    <div>
         <Demo/>
    </div>
  );
}

const Demo = forwardRef((props,ref)=>{

useImperativeHandle(ref,()=>({
  toggle(){
    console.log(123);
  }
}))

  return(
    <div ref={ref}>1234</div>

  )
})
```

online code :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/forwardref-z68drh?file=src/App.js

and I want to trigger child component's function on parent component... can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `ref` itself to `Demo` component:

```
function App() {
  const ref = useRef();
  return <Demo ref={ref}/>;
}
```

Then you can use `ref.current.toggle()` due to `useImperativeHandle`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/forwardref-z68drh-epz2xf?file=src/App.js